# Apply function in pandas using os.path module running slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-complexity

I'm using `.apply` on a DataFrame column (`Path`) to determine whether values represent a file or folder:

```
dir_tree_df['Type'] = dir_tree_df['Path'].apply(
        lambda row: 'File' if os.path.isfile(row) else 'Folder')
```

I'm finding the above to be very slow. Is this specifically to do with `os.path.isfile` or just user defined functions in general, and if so, is there a more efficient way of achieving my goal?

Comment: how many rows do you have? how long does it last? `apply` is slow in general.

Comment: It's part of script that'll be run on various SSD drives, so it'll vary. Could be hundreds  of files, could be thousands. It doesn't take too long with what I'm doing, but I can imagine it taking 10+ minutes for large folders.

Comment: are many of the files unique? repeated? Can't you index the files first with another approach?

Comment: If its applicable in your scenario. How about redirecting the directory output to a file (windows dir /s > files.txt,  ls >files.txt ) and parsing it? the properties/permission in the text files you can then use to determine if its a file or a folder.

Comment: @Naveed not too familiar with that approach. How would I go about coding that?

Comment: @mozway I'm not sure. All I know is there will be a lot of files, added to about a dozen or so SSD drives. I've just been asked to develop something that'll generate a tree like structure in Excel, among other things. I'll just be passing the script on to someone else to run as I won't have access to the SSD drives.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much fast this is, but this should get you what you want and use a function which is generally faster than lambda

I also just made up some data so you might have to play with it a little to reflect your own df.

```
def file_folder(x):
    if os.path.isfile(x) == True:
        return 'File'
    else:
        return 'Folder'

data = {
    'Column1' : [a file, a folder]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Type'] = df.apply(lambda x : file_folder(x['Column1']), axis = 1)
df
```

Comment: this won't make any significant difference, the limiting parameter is the loop and I/O access

Comment: So the best way to improve performance would be to put it in an array or something?

Comment: Likely not. maybe multithreading or prior indexing of the files

Comment: Alright awesome, I'll be keeping my eye on this post to see if I can use an answers later.